# Reset backlog after Socket server listen and response client

Tags: c#, sockets

I am a newbie in C#, and I have developed a Socket program.

```
private static void SetupServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
        serverSocket.Listen(1);
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }
```

But after server response a client, server is closed and not listen any time. How should I do to reset server after calling `Listen(backlog)` to maintain server for a long time?

This is my code in ClientSide:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace PC_Client
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void SendLoop()
    {

        string req = txtRequest.Text;
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);

        clientSocket.Send(buffer);
        byte[] receiveBuf = new byte[1024];
        int rec = clientSocket.Receive(receiveBuf);
        byte[] data = new byte[rec];
        Array.Copy(receiveBuf, data, rec);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));   
    }

    private void LoopConnect()
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        while(!clientSocket.Connected) 
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
            }
        }

        //Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendLoop();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the particulars of C#, but in general, you want to wrap your accept call in a loop like so:

```
while(true) {
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    respond to socket in background thread
}
```

This way, your main thread will always be able to listen for sockets (because its wrapped in a while loop, and continues to accept new connections) while also not being blocked while handling a client request (because the client socket is handled in a background thread)